# How to select the Typeform API on a hidden field?

Tags: php, curl, typeform

I need to select a completed form

In docs that seems like the only option :
https://api.typeform.com/forms/{form_id}/responses

How to make query by the hidden field that contains user_id to get the particular user's results. In the documentation this did not find

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but have you tried using the `query` param?

The [documentation](https://developer.typeform.com/responses/reference/retrieve-responses) says:

> `query` (string): Limit request to only responses that that include the specified term.

From my tests, the query argument will be searched in all the fields, including hidden fields.

For example:

```
GET https://api.typeform.com/forms/{form_id}/responses?query=<user_id_expected_in_hidden_field>
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>

200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "total_items": N,
  "page_count": M,
  "items": [ {...}, ... ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just only need to add a value that you would like to filter.

For example,

I want to get the reponse that contains phone number 123456789

```
https://api.typeform.com/forms/{form_id}/responses?query=123456789
```

Hope this help